# Bug in eclipse, not showing anything in Install Software Screen

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem with my eclipse. Whenever I go to the Install Software screen and put in a an update site, the screen shows nothing but when I click on the screen where I can select plugins they're there and I can actually go on to install the plugins.

[image: screenshot]

I actually saw the plugins showing the first time I used it and then I got this error:

> "A handler conflict occurred. This may
>   disable some commands"
>   eclipse.buildId=M20090917-0800
>   java.version=1.6.0_15 java.vendor=Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. BootLoader
>   constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk,
>   NL=en_PH Framework arguments: 
>   -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>   Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws
>   gtk -arch x86 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>
> Warning Sun Dec 27 14:13:49 PHT 2009
>   Conflict for
>   'org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor':HandlerActivation
>   (commandId=org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor,
>   handler=ActionHandler(org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@8eec22),
>   expression=AndExpression(AndExpression(org.eclipse.ui.SubActionBars$1@12f8a71,
>   ActivePartExpression(org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer@1e8b957)),
>   WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@270fc4)),
>   sourcePriority=1064961)
>   HandlerActivation(commandId=org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor,
>   handler=ActionHandler(org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@8eec22),
>   expression=AndExpression(AndExpression(org.eclipse.ui.SubActionBars$1@12f8a71,
>   ActivePartExpression(org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer@1e8b957))
>   ,WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@270fc4)),
>   sourcePriority=1064961)

Comment: also, for future reference, you might get quicker help by asking at http://superuser.com/ (and by asking in the middle of the day, not the middle of the night ;) )

Comment: err, I guess night depends on where you are... sorry for being kinda ego-centric there.

Comment: It's in the middle of the day when I first asked this question. GMT+8 hahaha. :D

Answer (score 25):

After reading items in this post I checked if deleting the **.metadata** folder fixed the situation. It fixed the problem but I lost my workspace settings. In order to fix this without losing your workspace settings you must delete only this file:

${YOUR_WORKSPACE_FOLDER}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui/**dialog_settings.xml**

Comment: did not change anything for me. I had to do the whole folder.

Comment: I tried this solution without exiting eclipse first and it did not work. However if you exit eclipse and then delete the file it should work; that's what worked for me. (Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit, Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2)

Comment: worked for me when trying to install [lsp4e](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.lsp4e)

Answer (score 8):

ggolebio had the right idea, and I'm assuming he got the information from https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=324729

Rather than deleting the file do the following:

- edit ${YOUR_WORKSPACE_FOLDER}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui/dialog_settings.xml
- set the AvailableNameColumnWidth to 420
- set the AvailableVersionColumnWidth to 140.
- Restart eclipse
- profit

This will not kill your workspace customizations like other solutions do.

Comment: I just experienced this issue in "eclipse-committers-2019-06-R-linux-gtk-x86_64" and this fixed it. The values for both were set to 0.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting the .metadata folder fixed it for me. Not sure of the cause but it was around the time I upgraded to Juno

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. First try creating a new workspace, and see if you still have the same problem. If so, then try deleting the `.metadata` directory from the corrupted workspace.

```
$ cd ~/<your-eclipse-corrupted-workspace>
$ rm -r .metadata/
```

I made the mistake of closing the "install new software" window after trying to filter "all available downloads" which was taking to long. That triggered the problem. I tried reinstalling. I uninstalled and reinstalled. I deleted my `~/.eclipse` folder. That made eclipse start in the default workspace, `~/workspace` which suddenly didn't have the problem. That's what made me realize that my problem was a corrupted workspace. As soon as I deleted the `.metadata` folder the problem disappeared.

There are bug reports on [LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/460944) and [eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=298708).

Comment: I made the same mistake as you, and your solution works, but the bug reports are referring to an empty update site list, which is a different problem.

Comment: For me it was sufficient to delete one file: .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui/dialog_settings.xml 
The problem was that Eclipse messed up some column width values.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the Eclipse package from Synaptic; it's been updated to the latest version just recently (though you may need to enable more recent updates from the Software Sources dialog or something).

Makes sure you install version 3.5.1-0ubuntu7 or later from Synaptic. I'm not in Ubuntu right now to check, but this bug has been fixed in that version and later. See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/443004).

If for some reason you can't do that, then do the workaround [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/443004/comments/13).

Comment: I am actually very very very new to Linux, I just installed Linux Mint on my laptop and well I dont' how to install "from Synaptic". Can you give me a link? Thanks. :D

Comment: Under System, Administration, the Synaptic Package Manager. Use the search button on the toolbar to search for eclipse, and then install the eclipse package. I think you'll catch on quickly; the package manager is pretty much the best part of Linux (compared to Windows)

Comment: Hi synaptic is saying that the latest version is 3.5.1-0ubuntu3 so I installed this anyway but obviously the bug is still there. I can't seem to find 3.5.1-0ubuntu7.

Answer (score 1):

They did not fix the issue. The solution of ggolebio, today 16 june **2015**, is still working.

`sudo rm /home/USERNAME/.workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui/dialog_settings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug somewhere. This could be specific to your OS or environment.

1. Start by checking the Error Log view (to show it, use the Window -> Show View option. See if you are getting any exceptions there.
2. To eliminate workspace issues: Try with a new workspace (simply switch to a new workspace, you can always switch back later).
3. To eliminate issues with your specific installation: Try with a clean Eclipse install. You can download a new installation from eclipse.org and install it in a different directory.
4. Search for existing bugs in [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/). If there are none, report yours. Attaching your configuration to the bug report might help (under About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration, copy and save to a text file).

Comment: The first time I used the Install Software Screen, the plugins were showing until I got the error above (see updated post).